# Root of resultant if and only if common root

Tags: proof-verification, resultant

I have solved (maybe) this exercise, but I'm not sure about my proof.
The exercise text is:

> Let $K$ be a field and let $f,g\in K[x_1,\dots ,x_n]$ with $x_n$ actually appearing in $f$ and $g$. Show that $f$ and $g$ have a common zero $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n-1},\alpha_n)$ if and only if $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n-1})$ is a zero of $R_{x_n}(f,g)$.

My solution is the following:

Claim.
$$R_{x_n}(f,g)(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n-1})=R_{x_n}(f(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n-1},x_n),g(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n-1},x_n))$$

If we have the claim, then the thesis follows easily:

- $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n-1})$ is a zero of $R_{x_n}(f,g)$ if and only if
- $R_{x_n}(f(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n-1},x_n),g(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n-1},x_n))=0$ if and only if
- $\exists \alpha_n$ common zero of $f(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n-1},x_n),g(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n-1},x_n)$ as polynomials in $K(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n-1})[x_n ]$, if and only if
- $\exists \alpha_n$ such that $f(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)=g(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)=0$.

I'm not sure about the Claim and about the sequence of equivalences (the all proof). It looks too easy, so I think I'm doing it wrong, maybe at formal level.

Comment: Have a look at [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Invariance_by_ring_homomorphisms), and consider the evaluation homomorphism. Maybe that helps.

Comment: The homomorphism must be on the coefficients in order to use those properties.

Comment: And the ring of coefficients is $K[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}]$, is it not? Isn't that how $R_{x_n}$ is defined in the first place?

Comment: Oh, that's true! Thanks. But what about the equivalences?

Comment: The statement isn't true unless $K$ is algebraically closed. (Though I'm not saying it is true otherwise... bad things can happen to resultants when a substitution deprives a polynomial of its leading term.)

Comment: Could you provide me an example, please?